# Center children in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I've got a 3 column `GridView` and 4 items.

So it happens that three of them appear on the first row, and the last one in the second row, but this one aligned to the left. I just wanted to know if there is possible to make it appear centered in the `GridView`. Like a 'T', I don't know if I explain... xD

Thank you :-)

**Edit:**

This is the layout that contains the `GridView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/section_title_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gd_home_grid">
    <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/home_grid_txori"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/home_grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_home_grid_item"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

By the way, `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` doesn't work in GridView

**Solution Edit:**

This issue is from years past, but I've been asked to post the solution and I had to find my old repo to get it :-)

As I said bellow in the comments, I couldn't achieve it only usin XML, so I had to trick a fake non-clickable + non-focusable item in 3rd position.

**It was my first App ever, so I didn't implement the recommended "ViewHolder" solution. I strongly recommend its usage**

This is how my getView() method looks like in the Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.home_grid_item, null);

        }

        /* In order to have 4th item centered in the 2nd row, we create an empty 3rd item */
        if (position == 3) {
            convertView.setFocusable(false);
            convertView.setClickable(false);
        } else {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbs[position]);
            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            textView.setText(mTitles[position]);

        }

        convertView.setTag(mTabTags[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

in the xml.

Comment: try looking around here.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:gravity

Comment: It's impossible to do it by xml params, so finally I player dirty and I've created an empty non-clickable+non-focusable item when position==3 in my Adapter. It works fine :-)

Comment: Actually, what I wanted, was to center the single items within the cells of the grid-views, but your answer put me on the right track (setting the gravity on the layout I use for the items.

Comment: @Wakka. Can you please share your code here. I also want to achieve the same layout dynamically depending on number of items. Thanks..

Comment: @YuDroid Done :-) It was my first App so you should use also the ViewHolder algorithm!

Comment: Working sample would be nice.  Which element do you center_horizontal, the parent, the gridview, the cells?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this problem.
I dynamicly set numcolumn when I know the column exactly.

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gr_single"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/pay_mode_icon_margin"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/pay_mode_icon_margin"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/pay_icon_width"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In the java.

```
mGridView.setNumColumns(mSingleImageViews.size());
mGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
```